# Heun's method for non-homogeneous LTI

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Heun's method for homogeneous system is simple enough:

$$\bar{x}_{k+1} = x_k + hf(x_k)$$
$$x_{k+1} = x_k + \frac{h}{2}\left( f(x_k) + f(\bar{x}_{k+1}) \right)$$

I have a non-homogeneous LTI system:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$$

where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -3730.2 & -26.15 \end{bmatrix}$, $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 26.04 \end{bmatrix}$, $u = 0.5\sin{3t}+0.4$

With Forward Euler's method, I have the following discretized state space:

$$A_d = I + hA$$
$$B_d = hB$$

With Heun's method, I have the following discretized state space:

$$A_d = I + hA + \frac{h^2}{2}A^2$$
$$B_d = hB + \frac{h^2}{2}AB$$

It's a simple enough system that I can get an exact analytical solution. When I compare the three, I notice that Heun's always does worse than forward Euler's after the initial transient dies out. For reference, $h=0.005$ and the initial conditions are all zero.

Is there a mistake with my derivation of Heun's for this LTI?

[image]

Comment: You have to use $u$ values from two different times, that can not be combined into a linear expression of a single time.

Comment: In practice, u is not known apriori. That's the whole point of the discretization.

Comment: Then you can not use the method and expect a better performance than with any other first-order method. What you can do is use explicit multi-step methods, where no control data from the "future" is required.

Comment: How can Simulink achieve better results with higher order discrete methods then? It has Heun solver and its performance is much better than Euler. Even if what you say is true, Heun should not be *worss* than Euler.

Comment: Then you have $u$ given as function of the state $x$ in some sense, so that you get either a closed ODE or DDE system, which can be solved with the appropriate higher-order methods.

Comment: No, u is independent. It could be stochastic for all intent and purpose.

Comment: Then you get a problem defining what the exact solution is that serves as reference for the error. // Again, if you modify Heun's method so that it is no longer Heun's method, then you can not expect the error order 2 of Heun's method in the result. In most modifications, consistency and thus error order 1 in preserved, but not more.

Comment: And it's worse than Euler?

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Order 1 gives just the asymptotic behavior, the coefficients for the leading error terms can be quite different.

Comment: In that case, if what you say is accurate, is there any point to use higher order discretization for ODE solutions at all, if the inputs are only sampled at the fundamental sample time (h) as zero-order hold? This is relevant, for example, in model-predictive control.

Comment: Please give step size used and initial condition, so that your example becomes reproducible. // What you say is true, it is among others the reason that simply applying standard Runge-Kutta methods to SDE is not useful. // If you adapt the sampling rate of the input to the step size, then what is the exact solution? If the object that gets approximated is that fluid, then it also becomes difficult to specify the order of convergence. You can have an exact solution for a fixed piecewise constant input, there you should get the usual error order.

Comment: Modified OP. Sampling rate cannot be faster than the step size because these things are ran on realtime schedulers. What I'm showing here is just a "toy" problem. With actual physical systems, the convergence and errors become impossible to define because of stochastic nature of measurements/inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an incorrectly implemented Heun method with a correctly applied Euler method. As the incorrect method still satisfies the basic consistency conditions, one gets a numerical result close to the solution, getting better for smaller step sizes. But as now both methods are of order 1, the factor of the leading term in the error expansion determines how good they look compared to a (more) exact solution.

If you look at the initial segment up to time $t=1.5$, you will see what looks like a reduced dampening factor in the incorrect method. This however is less visible if the step size is reduced to $h=0.001$. Such distortions usually occur when the method is executed close to the border of its stability region. This reduced dampening then also gives a "lengthening of the leash" as the solution is drawn along the forced oscillation of the input curve.

Comment: So what's the correct implementation of Heun's (or any explicit higher order method) for this problem, then, which was my original question?

Comment: That depends completely on what $u$ is. In the example, $u$ is a function of $t$, so the standard method applies. If $u$ depends on some history of states, it could be a DDE. If $u$ is random, it might be an SDE. All these have variants of the Heun method, but one can not apply the exact same formula as for $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$ where $f$ is smooth.

Comment: u is a function of time. But it's discretely sampled at the sampling time and no more. This is very typical of real-time systems that will only operate at their sampling rate.